# Dealing with DOM elements I want invisible to user

Tags: jquery, css

I have a footer that I want to be invisible to the user until they scroll to the bottom of my page. I am trying to do it all with CSS and just using JS to apply classes that will perform CSS transitions, but the problem is the footer has some anchors `<a></a>` in it and so my original method of just using opacity allows the user to still hover over the link and click before I want them to.

This led me to add the jQuery `$('.footer').hide()` and `$('.footer').show()` in place so that the DOM only appears when I want it to. However, doing this seems to have broken the CSS transition that was supposed to take place (now instead of an animation from 0 opacity to 0.8, it goes instantly).

Is there a solution anyone knows of that would allow me to hide the DOM completely but let me use CSS transitions on it as soon as it becomes available via `$.show()`?

This can be seen at [DaemonDeveloper.com](http://daemondeveloper.com)

Just navigate down to the "Why" section and observe.. The first CSS transition is broken, but the second that reveals the buttons works ok.

Comment: Shame on you for using tables for your layout with HTML5!

Comment: tables allowed me to create horizontal and vertically centered evenly spaced elements in like 2 minutes. Any other way I can think of would take a lot longer... what else would I use

Comment: `<div style="display:block; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto">I am centered.</div>` -- of course, without inline styles. Tables should always only be used for tabular data!

Comment: @RobW would it be "unshameful" to use an `<ul>` instead to present my footer layout? That also is meant to simply list things but people have been using them for years for hundreds of other uses like navigation menus and whatnot

Comment: Well, there is a `<footer>` element and a `<nav>`. Since your menu is a list of links, `<ul>`'s are appropriate.

Comment: @RobW oh you meant using tables for the main content on each slide.. I didn't want to use tables for that, but I couldn't think of an easier way to center vertically as well.. Horizontal is easy as you said with `margin:0 auto` but vertically is hard

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32510/discussion-between-matt-hintzke-and-rob-w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot transition an element that has been hidden with `display: none` (which is what jQuery's `hide()` is doing.

The best way around this is to hide the item with `visibility: hidden` and declare a `height` of zero. This way you can still apply the transition to `opacity` to get the effect you want by just manipulating classes.

**CSS**

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  height:0;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.show {
  visibility:visible;
  height:auto;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: well before the transition class is applied like `$.addClass('fadeIn')` I am doing `$.show()` to the DOM. Is that okay at least? but good idea about the visibility, I forgot about that.

Comment: I am referring to the css ``visibility`` property: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @MattHintzke I'd have to test that, but I believe that having ``display: none`` on the parent element will still block you from using your transition. You can use ``visibility`` or absolute positioning to show and hide your ``.footer``.

Comment: I know some people like to use absolute to place the element at like `margin-left:-9999px`, but I find it a little too hacky..what do you think?

Comment: I tried the visibility solution first, but it didn't work quite right because since the anchor icons (Facebook, Twitter, ect) also use the `.fadeIn` class, the `height:auto` works great for the `.footer` but breaks my styling for the icons because they have a defined height of `45px`. Instead I used the margin-left, which also deals with the cross-browser compat problem. check it out now

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers methods such as `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. There's also the `animate` method.

- http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
- http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
- http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: yeah thats the obsolete way of doing animations... I want pure CSS

Comment: It's far from obsolete. CSS3 animations exists, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations - if you're doing this already, and your `show()`/`hide()` is breaking this, then your callbacks are flawed.

Comment: ok not obsolete.. but slow. jQuery animation is pure JS, which is much slower than pure CSS which is ran in C/C++. I know about CSS3 animations, that is not the problem